# Keeping track of players in a game (Java)

Tags: java

I'm making a simple game for a bot in Discord. A word is printed and people have to guess the reading of the word and if they get it right, they get a point. They will have say 5 seconds to answer before the bot moves on. I wanna make this so that I don't have to specify the amount of players at the beginning of the game, people can just jump in.

Then once someone reaches a certain amount of points, they win the game.

```
public static void vocabGame (MessageReceivedEvent event, String level, int total) {
    int points = 0;


    //Pause the program for 10000 milliseconds, or 10 seconds, before starting.
    event.getTextChannel().sendMessage("`"+level+" vocab quiz starting in 10 seconds. \nFirst to reach "+total+" points wins.`").queue();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //Not sure what to do with this while loop condition
    while (points < total) {
        //Store random line from text file and store in text variable.
        String text = Reader.fileReader(level);


        //Using patterns and matchers, going to break apart the text from the text file. 
        //The question first
        Pattern question = Pattern.compile("\\{ \"question\": \"(.*?)\"");
        Matcher questionMatch = question.matcher(text);
        questionMatch.find();
        String word = questionMatch.group(1);

        //The answer second
        Pattern answer = Pattern.compile("\"answers\": [ \"(.*?)\"");
        Matcher answerMatch = answer.matcher(text);
        answerMatch.find();
        String ans = answerMatch.group(1);


        //Get image of word from dummyimage and then print. Picture size can be changed via the URL
        try {
            final BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new URL("https://dummyimage.com/300x100/000/fff.png&text="+word));
            ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("word.png"));
        } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Print picture with word on it
        Message message = new MessageBuilder().append("Word:").build();
        event.getTextChannel().sendFile(new File("word.png"), message).queue();


        //TODO figure out a way to make the program wait for input, not just putting it to sleep
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        points++; //this is temp
    }   
}
```

My question is how do I tackle keeping track of the points? I'm not asking you to write code for me, but just put me on the right track because I am unsure and haven't ever done anything like this before.

I was thinking about a while loop that kept grabbing user input while a timer was active, not that I know how to implement a timer. Because if no one answers, the bot moves on anyway.

Comment: Create a collection of the players' data...

Answer (score 0):

1)I don't see any class used for a Player, you could gather up data related to a player and keep a collection of players.

2) You should refer the [Observer Design Pattern](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/DesignPatternObserver/article.html) and let the players (1)register themselves and you process the entire updated Player list that have registered.

3) After your time passed for a game slot you loop though the player list and get the player having highest score.